# Multiple Mutations on a single object

Tags: relayjs, graphql-js

I try to have a `addColumn` and a `removeColumn` mutation on a `Chart` component.

But when I call

```
Relay.Store.commitUpdate(new RemoveChartColumnMutation({
  chart: this.props.viewer.chart,
  column: this.props.viewer.chart.columns[0]
})
```

I get this error

```
"Fragment \"F2\" cannot be spread here as objects of type "AddChartColumnPayload\" can never be of type \"RemoveChartColumnPayload\"."
```

What am I doing wrong here?

```
export default Relay.createContainer(Home, {
  fragments: {
    viewer: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on User {
        chart {
          columns
          ${AddChartColumnMutation.getFragment('chart')}
          ${RemoveChartColumnMutation.getFragment('chart')}
        }
      }`
  }
});
```

With these mutations

```
class AddChartColumnMutation extends Relay.Mutation {
  getMutation() {
    return Relay.QL`mutation {addChartColumn}`;
  }
  getVariables() {
    return {
      id: this.props.chart.id,
      key: this.props.key,
      aggregation: this.props.aggregation
    };
  }
  getFatQuery() {
    return Relay.QL`
      fragment on AddChartColumnPayload {
        chart {
          columns
        }
      }
    `;
  }
  getConfigs() {
    return [{
      type: 'FIELDS_CHANGE',
      fieldIDs: {
        chart: this.props.chart.id
      }
    }];
  }
  static fragments = {
    chart: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Chart {
        id
        type
      }
    `
  };
}
```

and

```
class RemoveChartColumnMutation extends Relay.Mutation {
  getMutation() {
    return Relay.QL`mutation {addChartColumn}`;
  }
  getVariables() {
    return {
      chartId: this.props.chart.id,
      columnId: this.props.column.id
    };
  }
  getFatQuery() {
    return Relay.QL`
      fragment on RemoveChartColumnPayload {
        chart {
          columns
        }
      }
    `;
  }
  getConfigs() {
    return [{
      type: 'FIELDS_CHANGE',
      fieldIDs: {
        chart: this.props.chart.id
      }
    }];
  }
  static fragments = {
    chart: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Chart {
        id
        type
      }
    `
  };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've just got a typo in your code. Looks like both mutations are calling the `addChartColumn` mutation, which would explain the error expecting the remove chart column payload.